# Wordpress: array_push creates array inside the previous array

Tags: php, wordpress, array-push

I want to create in WordPress `usermeta` data on `array()` with user favorite posts who he can add to this meta `favorite`.

If I use `array_push()` on `get_user_meta()` the array is nested in subsequent array.

```
my_operation(){    
   $meta_user_favorite = get_user_meta($user_id,"favorite");   
   array_push($meta_user_favorite, $post_id);    
   update_user_meta( $user_id, "favorite", $meta_user_favorite);  
}
```

After several such operations it's my result in `var_dump($meta_user_favorite);`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          int(726)
        }
        [1]=>
        int(713)
      }
      [1]=>
      int(710)
    }
    [1]=>
    int(688)
  }
}
```

It should be in one array, what I'm doing wrong?

```
array(1) {
      [0]=>int(726)
      [0]=>int(713)
      [0]=>int(710)
      [0]=>int(688)
}
```

Comment: `$meta_user_favorite = array_merge($meta_user_favorite, $post_id);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs for [`get_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). The third argument, which you're omitting, is `$single`, which defaults to `false`, and determines whether to return an array or the value. If you pass `true` to that (which honestly, I use in 95% of my use-cases when dealing with user and post meta), it should work.

```
my_operation(){
    $meta_user_favorite = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite', true );   
    array_push( $meta_user_favorite, $post_id );    
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite', $meta_user_favorite );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and now it's resolved. This should be marked as the accepted answer